# How to Query just all the documents name of index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

PS: I'm new to elasticsearch

`http://localhost:9200/indexname/domains/<mydocname>`

Let's suppose we have `indexname` as our index and i'm uploading a lot of documents at `<mydoc>` with domain names ex:

`http://localhost:9200/indexname/domains/google.com`
`http://localhost:9200/indexname/domains/company.com`

Looking at `http://localhost:9200/indexname/_count` , says that we have `"count": 119687` amount of documents.

I just want my elastic search to return the **document names** of all `119687` entries which are domain names.

How do I achieve that and is it possible to achieve that in one single query?

Comment: So you want to have [google.com, company.com] in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example : `http://localhost:9200/indexname/domains/google.com` I am assuming your doc_type is `domains` and doc id/"document name" is `google.com`.

`_id` is the document name here which is always part of the response. You can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering) to disable source and it will show only something like below:

```
GET indexname/_search
{
  "_source": false
}
```

Output

```
{
...
    "hits" : [
          {
            "_index" : "indexname",
            "_type" : "domains",
            "_id" : "google.com",
            "_score" : 1.0           
          }
    ]
...
}
```

If `documentname` is a field that is mapped, then you can still use source filtering to include only that field.

```
 GET indexname/_search
 {
   "_source": ["documentname"]
 }
```